# simple tab system in Angularjs error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I'm trying to create a simple tab system in angularjs, but whenever I try to bind data on ng-click on the a or li tags of my template I get this error:

Syntax Error: Token '' {1} at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

I been searching for hours can't figure out what's causing the problem

here's my code:

```
    <div id="tabs">        
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="file in files" ng-click="tab = {{$index}}">
             <a href="#">{{file.file_name}}.{{file.file_extension}}</a>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div>

                    <!-- tab container -->
   <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab" ng-repeat="doc in files" ng-show="tab == {{$index}}">
              {{doc.file_name}}.{{doc.file_extension}}
        </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried wrapping {{$index}} in single quotes, that fixes the problem but the tabs don't work when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move this out of the inline logic and into a function, for example `$scope.setTabIndex`, like so:

```
$scope.setTabIndex = function(index) {
  $scope.tab = index;
}
```

And then in your markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="file in files" ng-click="setTabIndex($index)">
```

And for the `ng-show`, just remove the curly braces around `$index`:

```
<div class="tab" ng-repeat="doc in files" ng-show="tab == $index">
```

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/senodibatu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) as jsBin